# SQL Dynamic join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Please see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2506f/2/0

I have two tables.  One is a general record, and the other is a table containing related documents that link to that record.

In my example I've created a straightforward query which shows all records and their associated documents.  This is fine, but I want a more complex situation.

In the 'mainrecord' table there is a 'multiple' field.  If this is 0, then I only want the most recent document from the documents table (that is, with the highest ID).  If it is 1, I want to join all linked documents.

So, rather than the result of the query being this:-

```
ID  NAME    MULTIPLE    DOCUMENTNAME    IDLINK
1   One     1           first document    1
1   One     1           second document   1
2   Two     0           third document    2
2   Two     0           fourth document   2
3   Three   1           fifth document    3
3   Three   1           sixth document    3
```

It should look like this:-

```
ID  NAME    MULTIPLE    DOCUMENTNAME    IDLINK
1   One     1           first document    1
1   One     1           second document   1
2   Two     0           fourth document   2
3   Three   1           fifth document    3
3   Three   1           sixth document    3
```

Is there a way of including this condition into my query to get the results I'm after.  I'm happy to explain further if needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your current setup does not allow you to select "the most recent document", as all documents for "Two" have got the same ID. So at the moment there is no way of knowing which one to select in that case.

Comment: There is an ID in the fiddle.  For some reason it's not showing in the query results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH myData
AS
(SELECT mainrecord.*, documentlinks.documentName, documentlinks.idlink,
Row_number()
                  OVER (
                    partition BY mainrecord.ID
                    ORDER BY mainrecord.ID ASC) AS ROWNUM
FROM mainrecord INNER JOIN documentlinks
ON mainrecord.id = documentlinks.idlink)
SELECT *
FROM mydata o
WHERE multiple = 0 AND rownum =
(SELECT max(rownum) FROM mydata i WHERE i.id = o.id)
UNION
SELECT *
FROM myData
WHERE multiple = 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2506f/57

Answer (score 2):

Another solution (tested at **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2506f/55)**):

```
SELECT m.*, 
       d.id as did, d.documentName, d.IDLink
FROM mainrecord AS m
  JOIN documentlinks AS d
    ON  d.IDLink = m.id 
    AND m.multiple = 1 

UNION ALL

SELECT m.*, 
       d.id as did, d.documentName, d.IDLink
FROM mainrecord AS m
  JOIN
    ( SELECT d.IDLink
           , MAX(d.id) AS did
      FROM mainrecord AS m
        JOIN documentlinks AS d
          ON  d.IDLink = m.id 
          AND m.multiple = 0
      GROUP BY d.IDLink
    ) AS g
    ON g.IDLink = m.id 
  JOIN documentlinks AS d
    ON  d.id = g.did

ORDER BY id, did ;
```

Answer (score 1):

This will probably do:

```
SELECT mainrecord.name, documentlinks.documentname
FROM documentlinks
INNER JOIN mainrecord ON mainrecord.id = documentlinks.IDLink AND multiple = 1

UNION

SELECT mainrecord.name, documentlinks.documentname
FROM (SELECT max(id) id, IDLink FROM documentlinks group by IDLink) maxdocuments
INNER JOIN documentlinks ON documentlinks.id = maxdocuments.id
INNER JOIN mainrecord ON mainrecord.id = documentlinks.IDLink AND multiple = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2506f/52)

```
select
    m.ID, m.name, m.multiple, dl.idlink,
    dl.documentName
from mainrecord as m
    left outer join documentlinks as dl on dl.IDlink = m.id
where
    m.multiple = 1 or 
    not exists (select * from documentlinks as t where t.idlink = m.id and t.id < dl.id)
```

Comment: What I mean is that I want the most recently added document record that relates to the current mainrecord row.  This can be identified easily by the documentlinks.ID field..

Comment: take a look at my second solution. It's very simple and gives correct results

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
select * from mainrecord a inner join documentlinks b on a.Id=b.IDLink 
where b.id=(case 
   when a.multiple=1 then b.id 
   else (select max(id) from documentlinks c where c.IDLink=b.IDLink) end)
```